# Load custom view from .xib doesn't fit to iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, autolayout

I m using `Autolayout` in my app.

When I load my custom `UIView` from `.xib` **from `viewDidLoad`** it's size is (300,325) like it should be, but on `iPhone6+` is't actually (394, 493).

But when I load my custom `UIView` from `.xib` after that (somewhere) the size isn't change ( stay (300, 325) ) to the `iPhone6+` scale.

Can u help with the reason and the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Add new Constraints for specific UIView. Then it's automatically resize the View.

Otherwise if your Xib somewhere ... You have to set frame programmatically based on device.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The custom view has a constraints but to the custom view's container hasn't, I simply added the view to the center container view. Do U think that I need to set it by hand still?